# From Squarespace to Magento?

Tags: migration, data-migration

I'm going to move from Squarespace to Magento- does anyone have any recommendations on how to get my products, customer and order information into Magento?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question doesn't belong to Magento Stack Exchange